# Trampoline on shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, games-toys

Is there an issue with bouncing on a trampoline on shabbat? This is not about setting up a trampoline, but if one can bounce and play on a trampoline that was set up before shabbos.

Comment: Why would you think it isn't?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchasa 16:39 makes a clear distinction:

(Feldheim Edition. Vol. 1, p.196)

> a. Running and **jumping games**, such as tag, hide-and-seek and skipping with a rope are permitted, but
>
> b. the performance of physical exercises is prohibited.

So, whilst it doesn't mention trampolining outright, if this jumping is purely for enjoyment and not exercise motivated it would be allowed. This falls in line with the [Shulchan Aruch OC 301:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.301.2?lang=bi&with=Commentary%20ConnectionsList&lang2=en)

On further research, I came across Halachically Speaking on the Summer [here - p.7](https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol12Issue11.pdf)

> **Trampoline**
>
> Trampolines may be used on Shabbos, and there is no issue with making a hole in the ground,<sup>1</sup> but one may not put it together on Shabbos.<sup>2</sup>

---

> <sup>1</sup>[Kovetz Halachos L’meonos Hakayitz, page 154:84](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=57789&st=&pgnum=154&hilite=). See [Nishmas Shabbos 6:275](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9696&st=&pgnum=276&hilite=)
>
> <sup>2</sup>[Avnei Yushpei 7:35:1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53858&st=&pgnum=92&hilite=).

Comment: As always, great job! Maybe the most quoted sefer this week :)

Comment: Thanks @Shmuel! These later sources say it even more outright!

Comment: So its a question of the mindset? As long as there is something chasing me in a gameified version (software for example), i can perform all exercises?

Comment: @Pica - I'm sorry I don't understand what you're asking? What has software got to do with it?

Comment: If i program a game of tag, that hunts me while im on the trampoline - for example in AugmentedReality, i can exercise all day?

Comment: No. Here we are simply jumping on a trampoline for pleasure. What you describe is using something that it muktzeh?!

Comment: To reiterate, in addition, you can't do things for exercise.

Comment: Games generally involve multiple people. If you're by yourself skipping rope, it seems like exercise. But if someone else is swinging the rope, and you're singing jumping songs together, that seems like a game.

Comment: or if several of you are jumping and singing together.

Comment: @Barmar - even if a person is skipping by themselves if it is for pleasure it is allowed. If they are doing an intense workout then it is not allowed.

Comment: I know the "games involve multiple people" is not a rigid definition, since there are lots of solitaire games.

Comment: Seems like a very fuzzy line, since many people really enjoy their exercise.

Comment: I would imagine it is one thing to do a light jump session which can possibly be defined also as "light exercise" but we're talking about avoiding a proper intense workout session